# Get the date ranges excluding the stoppage timings

Tags: scala, datetime, if-statement, localtime

Here is my scala case class DateRange:

```
case class DateRange(startDT: DateTime, endDT: DateTime)
```

The sample input data (Joda):

```
val dt1 = DateTime.parse("2016-01-04T03:00:00.000Z") // dt1 will always the range start date time 
val dt2 = DateTime.parse("2016-01-05T04:00:00.000Z") // dt2 will always the range end date time  

val dr = DateRange(dt1, dt2) // container to hold the date ranges

val st = LocalTime.parse("13:00:00") // st will always the stoppage start time
val et = LocalTime.parse("02:00:00") // et will always the stoppage end time
```

I am trying to get the result as `List[DateRange]` excluding the stoppage timing intervals. The Date ranges and time ranges maybe anything.

Desired output for the above input data:

```
List(DateRange(2016-01-04T03:00:00.000Z,2016-01-04T13:00:00.000Z),DateRange(2016-01-05T02:00:00.000Z,2016-01-05T04:00:00.000Z))
```

I tried like this:

```
val result = if (st.isBefore(et)) {
    if (dr.startDT.isBefore(dr.endDT) && st.isAfter(dr.startDT.toLocalTime)) {
      DateRange(dr.startDT.withTime(st), dr.startDT.withTime(et))
    } else if (dr.startDT.isBefore(dr.endDT) && st.isBefore(dr.startDT.toLocalTime)) {
      DateRange(dr.endDT.withTime(st), dr.endDT.withTime(et))
    } else {
      DateRange(dr.startDT.withTime(st), dr.startDT.withTime(et))
    }
  }
  else {
    if (dr.startDT.isBefore(dr.endDT) && et.isBefore(dr.endDT.toLocalTime) && st.isBefore(dr.endDT.toLocalTime)) {
      DateRange(dr.startDT.withTime(st), dr.endDT.withTime(23, 59, 59, 999))
    } else if (dr.startDT.isBefore(dr.endDT) && et.isBefore(dr.endDT.toLocalTime) && st.isAfter(dr.endDT.toLocalTime)) {
      DateRange(dr.startDT, dr.endDT.withTime(et))
    } else if (dr.startDT.isBefore(dr.endDT) && et.isBefore(dr.endDT.toLocalTime) && st.isAfter(dr.endDT.toLocalTime)) {
      DateRange(dr.startDT, dr.endDT.withTime(et))
    }  else {
      DateRange(dr.startDT.withTime(st), dr.endDT.withTime(et))
    }
```

Comment: If "st will always the stoppage start time" and "et will always the stoppage end time" how can st.isBefore(et) be false?

Comment: tldr find a way to sort it

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov ...stoppage start time may start by the end of the day and stoppage end time may end next day morning.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
object Splitter extends App {

  val shiftStartDate = DateTime.parse("2016-01-04T06:00:00.000")
  val shiftEndDate = DateTime.parse("2016-01-04T16:00:00.000")

  val st = LocalTime.parse("23:00:00")
  val et = LocalTime.parse("08:00:00")


  val stoppageStartDate = shiftStartDate.toLocalDate.toDateTime(st)
  val StoppageEndDate = if(st.isBefore(et)){
    shiftStartDate.toLocalDate.toDateTime(et)
  }else{
    shiftStartDate.toLocalDate.toDateTime(et).plusDays(1)
  }
  val result = if ((stoppageStartDate.isAfter(shiftStartDate) || stoppageStartDate.isEqual(shiftStartDate)) &&
    (StoppageEndDate.isBefore(shiftEndDate) || StoppageEndDate.isEqual(shiftEndDate))) {
    List(DateRange(shiftStartDate, stoppageStartDate), DateRange(StoppageEndDate, shiftEndDate))
  } else if ((stoppageStartDate.isAfter(shiftStartDate) || stoppageStartDate.isEqual(shiftStartDate)) &&
    StoppageEndDate.isAfter(shiftEndDate) && stoppageStartDate.isBefore(shiftEndDate)) {
    List(DateRange(shiftStartDate, stoppageStartDate))
  }
  else if (stoppageStartDate.isBefore(shiftStartDate) && (StoppageEndDate.isBefore(shiftEndDate) ||
    StoppageEndDate.isEqual(shiftEndDate)) && StoppageEndDate.isAfter(shiftStartDate)) {
    List(DateRange(StoppageEndDate, shiftEndDate))
  } else if (stoppageStartDate.isBefore(shiftStartDate) && StoppageEndDate.isAfter(shiftEndDate)) {
    Nil
  } else {
    List(DateRange(shiftStartDate, shiftEndDate))
  }
  println(">>>>  " + result.result.filterNot(x=>x.startTS==x.endTS))
}
```